# Automate file upload on sharepoint

Tags: build, automation

Daily I need to upload 10-15 files on a sharepoint which takes my 5-10 min.

I just want to automate this process so that it will save my time.

If anyone have any solution for this please share.

Solution in any lang will be welcomed

Thanks and regards,

Shrikant Salunke

Comment: AutoIT provides a simple and easy to use interface for this type of thing.  It compiles to an executable and I have used it for the exact task that you are working on and it is well documented.

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using and where are you trying to upload files from? Are you trying to upload files from inside the SharePoint farm?